# Pushing info to an android app via PHP server?

Tags: java, android, mobile, polling, long-polling

Is there a way to keep a connection open between an Android app and a PHP script, so if there are any updates, the PHP script can push notifications out to the android app, rather than the app having to make a HTTP request every X minutes to ask for any updates?

I know this isn't possible via Ajax without installing things on the server side to enable them, but I'm wondering if its any different on Android.

E.g if I did the following on the PHP side:

```
<?
set_time_limit(0);
while (true)
{
   $updates = $updater->find();
   if ($updates)
      ob_flush( $updates->getAsJSON() );
   sleep(60);
}
?>
```

Will something like this work to keep a connection open and push out updates to the android app?

The server is running Apache and PHP 5.

Comment: You are looking for something comparable as a websocket. See http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Comment: @hakra I'd prefer not having to install anything server side or change any server settings. Can't a web socket connection be opened via java on the android side, the PHP script just push out new data using ob_flush() and Android/Java receiving the data?

Comment: You should first of all invest some time and research the problem a bit. You will come up with more and more specifics here if you get feedback instead of doing your homework first. E.g. first of all find out *which* protocols your android offers for messaging via HTTP. Then you can look if there is a solution with PHP. And yes, it might be that you need to install something. That's how it is in computing. So please research the one or other part first, e.g. tell what exactly you want to use on the android side or the server-side. Everything else is a bit open for a Q&A site.

Comment: @hakra If I knew what I wanted to use, why would I be asking here? I've given the details of my situation, if you're unwilling or unable to answer then kindly just move on to other questions and leave this for someone who will answer.

Comment: It is not a problem to not know everything, however this website is not for so called "Shopping Recommendations". Instead be more specific what you need and ask a specific question. Sure the lines can be shady, however take care not ending up as a *Help Vampire*. Enable yourself in solving your questions. E.g. that suggestion code you posted, tell use whether it did work for you or not. And if it didn't work what the problem was. Just ask a question to find a solution. But ask the question to yourself as well.

Comment: @hakra I'm specific that I want to maintain a persistant connection between an Android app and a PHP script being run on an Apache server.  This question is allowed within the rules of this site. Please move on to other questions.

Comment: Stalking your questions? That's new to me. If you're not comfortable with my comments just ignore them, there is no need to be rude.

Comment: It would probably be better for your Android app to initiate a separate, brief poll every X seconds, than to hold a connection open. I'd guess the latter would drain the battery faster. You could even implement logic on the server that says 'call back in X seconds', so at times of heavy load, all applications quickly learn to call less frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work *in theory*, but will also cause unneeded CPU usage, because you look for updates every minute, and, depending on `$updater` implementation, this may waste CPU, memory and IO. If you want an event-driven communication not to waste resources, you need an event-based backend - and there are plenty of them out there, but none in PHP, and that's because it's a PHP limit. There's no way, in a PHP script, to go multithread and `wait()`, so basically you can't implement the *Observer* pattern, and this in turn prevents them from writing event-driven libraries in PHP.

I don't think you want to do this. Unless you can **without any doubt** count users on your fingers, this task cannot be handled by PHP. It's not an issue with the webserver, it's an issue with PHP itself. Each PHP request (either via `mod_php`, fcgi, `php-fpm`) is handled with a new PHP process. This makes it impossible to scale, and that's why you need to install use other server-side technologies to implement long polling.

Comment: Well, when a user on Android is done, the connection will be terminated and the PHP script should as a result be terminated too. Can you tell me how to implement this connection on the Android side, would I be using the HTTPNetConnection?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.libevent.php and you can also threading on unix in PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php .

Comment: @hakra sounds interesting, never heard of it. However, can it be used to write a socket.io equivalent?

Comment: I think those other softwares are using libevent, too. Rasmus Lerdorf has some nice examples together with 0MQ in the PHP UK 2012 talk: http://vimeo.com/channels/phpuk2012

Comment: @hakra it seems that [PCNTL can't be used in a webserver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php). Libevent may be a good starting point, but [the examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libevent.examples.php) are a bit too low level to be easily understood

Comment: Check the talk as well, the slides are online, too: http://talks.php.net/index.php/PHP - Next to that, create your own example and put it online. There are always different needs and examples are just examples. You can also extend the PHP manual, there is an edit link in the top-right corner of each page (hint ;)).

Comment: @ClickUpvote there's nothing special [on the Android part](http://pastebin.com/T2tEnvW6).

Comment: @hakra as far as I understand, you are telling that PHP *the language* can go multithread and handle server events. However, this quite diverges from the usual PHP *programming model*, and also requires a nonstandard *deployment environment*. IMHO every language that can be extended with native code can be used to do almost *everything*, but there's no use in bending PHP in such a way, because you don't have the *surrounding tools* other solutions have, and in tools and ecosystem is the real value that makes a possible alternative the right one

Comment: @Raffaele: Yes you are right, and I've seen some users who went to multi threading / signalling got lost. One principle in PHP is historically shared nothing. However another one is "PHP is glue". So what should I add to your comment ;) And you need to know I'm fan of fastcgi - in a server module multithreaded PHP can go gaga I suppose.

Comment: Although its for about two years ago,but for other ,i think using `node.js` will help in this condition.